# How to make userscript auto update from private domain/github?

Tags: tampermonkey, auto-update, userscripts

I am developing a userscript for Tampermonkey and storing it on private Github, that belongs to my company. I can't upload the code on a public server. The auto update feature of the script doesn't seem to work.

1. Is Tampermonkey using its own servers to check for updates?
2. Is it possible to make userscript auto update itself from private domain?

I am using these properties in userscript:

```
// @downloadURL  https://github02.private.domain/raw/github-username/repo-name/master/userscript.js
// @updateURL    https://github02.private.domain/raw/github-username/repo-name/master/userscript.js
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? And if, how? I have a similar situation.

Comment: Hi, @Fred please check the selected answer to this problem and let me know if it has helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the auto update actually works on a private domain, but there were 2 problems:

1. I entered an incorrect URL. I copied the link AFTER opening the RAW file on GitHub, but you need to copy the link from the button that leads to the RAW version of the file. The link is only slightly different, so it was hard to notice at first.

Incorrect URL: https://github.com/raw/username/your-repo/main/script.user.js
Correct URL: https://github.com/username/your-repo/raw/main/script.user.js

[image: Copy the link from RAW button]

2. Second issue is that the script file name actually needs to end with "**.user.js**" (!), like in example above. I don't see that mentioned anywhere. Everyone is doing it like this in examples on Stackoverflow, but no one explains, that this is a requirement!

Comment: For anyone else that runs into this, the branch name is now `main` not `master`.

Comment: @ChrisBarr thanks, I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your userscript on [Github Page](https://docs.github.com/en/pages). After you can use your public github page link for make update.

Comment: Unfortunately that's impossible since it's a company owned code. I should've mentioned that in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Even better: You can remove the updateURL and open the `raw` file in the repository browser view. Tampermonkey will detect the file and offers to (re)install it. Make sure the version is counted up!

Here is a neat workflow:

- Write your script in the IDE of your choice
- Use the git workflow creating a central repository
- Open the `raw` file with your browser in the repository

Tampermonkey will check for updates there automatically.